# How can I change a set of objects colour transition location in Z Axis?

Tags: texturing, materials, color

I want the colour of stairs change according to their position, I tried obj info node with Mix RGB and got the result below, however I want to change the transition position in Z axis, colour ramp didn't help, it only changes the transition power.
Stairs are not one objects, they are separete objects using same material in Cycles. thanks

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use '*object*' from the texture coordinate node :

[image]

The object output (from texture coordinates) is decomposed into X, Y, Z. Here only Z interests us.

The math node is here to tune the overall scale (real Z variation) to fit into the ramp (0 to 1).
I used divide and 12 as value because the stairs here are 12 meters tall.

On right : the stairs made with an array modifier
On left : separated objects

Edit : note that the colorramp is not mandatory here. You can short circuit it.

Comment: for some reason I'm not getting what you're getting, here is how it looks when I try it as you described. each step have a gradient effect unlike in your screenshot they don't make a unified effect. I  don't know
http://i.hizliresim.com/aX5p3O.png

Comment: @ideorium. That can be a scale or rotation effect (check your objects). If not, can you upload your file ?

Comment: here is the file http://www.pasteall.org/blend/43252
one other thing bothering me is, when I apply ARRAY modifier , I get each stairs have identical noise pattern as bump, hence I made them all separate objects, is it possible to have different noise for each step when array applied ?

Comment: @ideorium, I ignore why, but it works with your file if you set the first step cube as 'object' in the texture coordinate node. I have compared with my file and it is not necessary here. For the noise pattern, same principle. Here is your file back [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1808" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1808/)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you changed on the file you sent back, even though it looks same to my original file. When I try -even though everything seems same, I don't get it , and yes all objects are already connected with Object in text.coordinate. Can you please explain a bit more explicit, thanks

Comment: @ideorium, An image is better : https://i.gyazo.com/78e8ac8675c2f7b2d4262592e88cbd7f.jpg

Comment: thanks yes now it works when the very bottom object is selected.